# Json Serialisers vs .net serialised classes for JQuery AJAX result data

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

What is the most effective way to pass data from .net (c#, vb.net) Web Service to the client side using JQuery AJAX ?

A) Using Newtonsoft JSON serialization eg

```
 <WebInvoke(Method:="*", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/abc", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Public Function GetDontMissItems(JsonParams As RequestDataTypes.DontMissParams) As String
  objDontMissItems = Helper.Instance.GetDontMissNews(JsonParams.FeaturedCategoryId, QtyOfNumberOfItems, JsonParams.Randomize, If(JsonParams.NotInIDs = Nothing, "", JsonParams.NotInIDs))

   Dim strSerialzed As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objDontMissItems)

   Return strSerialzed
   End Function
```

Or

B) passing a Serialized class from the web service to the AJAX call eg

```
<Serializable>
Public Class clsPoll
    Public Property answerID As Integer
    Public Property questionRef As String
    Public Property votePercentage As String

End Class



<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Function InsertPoll(ByVal jsonData As clsPoll) As List(Of clsPoll)
    Dim dtVotests As DataSet = objAnswer.CalculateVote(jsonData.questionRef, 1)
    Dim lstPoll As New List(Of clsPoll)
        For Each drVotests As DataRow In dtVotests.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim objPollTemp As New clsPoll
            objPollTemp.answerID = drVotests("id")
            objPollTemp.questionRef = jsonData.questionRef
            objPollTemp.votePercentage = drVotests("p")
            lstPoll.Add(objPollTemp)
        Next
    Return lstPoll
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in server side pass it like this

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { errMsg = "test" });
```